# How to add MS EDGE in Eclipse from MarketPlace or is there any source to import

Tags: java, eclipse, microsoft-edge, code-composer

[image: reference image]

This image is for reference, and am trying to get the same to my preference list, tried downloading collabNet, polyglot .. please suggest which will do the same - or is there any external source to import!

Comment: are you want to add Edge in browser preference to run application right?

Comment: yes, I need  "EDGE" in my Preferences  menu as a option